# Missing data responses while using Python/Pyserial to communicate with RS232 Serial Port

Tags: python, encode, pyserial

I'm using python and pyserial to try sending command and getting responses. Here is my example code:

```
import serial           
ComPort = serial.Serial('COM4') # open COM4
ComPort.baudrate = 115200
ComPort.bytesize = 8
ComPort.parity   = 'N'
ComPort.stopbits = 1
ComPort.timeout  = 1
a= "FE0652"
data = a.decode('hex')
No = ComPort.write(serial.to_bytes(data))
msg = ComPort.read(1024)
print (msg.encode('hex'))
```

I used another tool written by C, it shows output correctly and fully. But with Python, it's missing almost half of responses. For example:

Expected:

```
ff5206
ff0023
ff0002
ff8080
ff8080
ff8080
ff8080
ff8003
......
```

Observed:

```
ff5206
ff0023
ff8080
ff8080
ff8003
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some delay between write and read:

```
time.sleep(0.01)
```

Also, try to read byte-wise:

```
s=''
while ComPort.inWaiting() > 0:
    s += ComPort.read(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! I already tried but no luck. When I tried to read byte-wise, it dropped the responses after the very first data, and randomly...sometime got only 1, sometime 2,3...I'm not sure if the problem is because of responding too fast so pyserial dropouts responses, or it is because of encode part...